# Reading a file into a linked list

Tags: c, file-io, linked-list, scanf

I'm trying to read a file that contains the following.

```
59878, Moby Dick
442419, The Peach
535, Moby Dick
12, History of War
```

I have a linked list that holds integer types and another that holds a char and linked list pointer. This is a node in the latter linked list:

```
typedef struct Node {
   struct Node* prev;
   char *title;
   ListRef library; //Pointer to a different linked list
   struct Node* next;
} Node; 

typedef struct Node* NodeRef;

NodeRef newNode(char *bookTitle, List LL) {
  NodeRef node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
  node->next = node->prev = NULL;
  node->title = (char*)calloc(60, sizeof(char));
  node->library = newList();
  node->library = LL;
  node->title = bookTitle;
return(node);
```

}

Comment: What's the difference between "read values from a file" and "read file input"? Could you give us a [minimal complete example](http://www.sscce.org)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what that extraneous sentence was doing there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store the `title` with

```
node->title = strdup(bookTitle);
```

Remove the `calloc` line, as `strdup` will do the memory allocation for you.

---

As the code is currently written, you allocate memory for the string, but then the line

```
node->title = bookTitle;
```

changes the pointer to so that it points to the buffer that `bookTitle` points to. Presumably, you are reusing the `bookTitle` buffer, so at the end of the program all of the titles point to the same buffer, and that buffer contains the last title read from the file.

Comment: Considering that you're assuming a maximum length, which is wise, you might want to use `strndup` with a length of 60 instead of `strdup` (this is good practice anyway). Pedagogically, it's also worth mentioning is that this causes a memory leak: the memory allocated for `node->title` will never be able to be freed.

Comment: I see, now I understand. Thank you both for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
NodeRef newNode(char *bookTitle, List LL) {
  NodeRef node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

FYI: The above line does not need to cast the value returned by malloc().  Instead, the line could be: `NodeRef node = malloc(sizeof(Node));`

```
  node->next = node->prev = NULL;
  node->title = (char*)calloc(60, sizeof(char));
```

Now node->title points to an allocated block of 60 bytes.

```
  node->library = newList();
  node->library = LL;
  node->title = bookTitle;
```

So, booktitle is a pointer to memory containing a string.  The above statement causes node->title  to point at the same thing that bookTitle is pointing to. Too bad for the  allocated block of 60 characters it was previously pointing to; that memory is now irrecoverably orphaned.  (This is not what was intended, I'm sure).

The above line should be changed to something like the following:

```
  // Assumption: bookTitle contains a properly terminated C string.
  node->title = strdup(bookTitle); 
  if(NULL == node->title)
     {
     fprintf(stderr, "strdup() failed!\n");
     /* and handle the error, even though you may never actually see it... */
     ...
     }

  return(node);
}
```

As new nodes were created, they all pointed to the same item, the address contained in 'bookTitle'.  Hence, when printing out the list, That's (dangerously) what you got.  The book title from the last book added was pointed to by all nodes.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I've only recently started using C.